# io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException while running cucumber code

Tags: junit, cucumber

I have developed a UI Automation project using Cucumber. When I try to run a test using cucumber and JUnit runner I receive: io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step "user is on Goibibo application login page" is undefined. You can implement it using tne snippet(s) below:

The Project Structure is as follows :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjUaZ.png)

TestRunner.java code is as follows :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAPgB.png)

POM.xml dependencies -

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory> 
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*TestRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
  <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit.</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Glue should be a package name. Not a class name.

Comment: I added the package name, then i am getting error " steps undefined, please define the steps "

Comment: Thanks @mpkorstanje, I am able to run now. But if i have multiple step definition files, and i want to run a particular step definition file, do i need to use tags for the same .

Comment: @TapashiSharmaRoy- how do you fix the issue, can you explain here. facing the same issue.